# Camel-restdsl and fabric8 http-gateway

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, fabric8

I got a camel-restdsl route (among others) running on JBoss Fuse 6.2, I'd like to know if it is possible to have it gateway'ed by the fabri8 http-gateway. I know that is would work for CXF rest services implemented there but don't see any documentation about REST services implemented with RestDSL. 
The route relies on on the restlet component (though I may have it changed to jetty or whatever other it may work).

Any pointers will be much appreciated!

Comment: I am looking into this as well on Fuse ESB 6.2 but I cannot get it to work. If you look at the Fabric8 guide at https://fabric8.io/gitbook/gateway.html it mentions that REST APIs are registered on the /fabric/registry/clusters/apis/rest Zookeeper path. You can view this in Hawt.io under Services > Registry. I only see the "old-fashioned" CXFRS service classes there, but not the Camel Rest DSL endpoints I have deployed.

Comment: Also still looking for an answer and would appreciate any hint! Thanks

Comment: ... and found the answer finally:https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjyxYLulKjYAhXIIewKHSlDAWAQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Faccess.redhat.com%2Fsolutions%2F2916501&usg=AOvVaw3DtJospwYgdrqKLNNmSmJN